# Access form button to generate and filter existing report

Tags: ms-access

I have a form that provides my users with a summary of vacation time (Associate Summary). I also have a report that generates the summary information in report format for email and printing (Summary).  Both work fine independently with the summary selecting the individual user based on a ComboBox, and the report pulles all users.  I am looking for a way to place a command button on the Form (Associate Summary) to open and filter the report (Summary) to the user name that is currently displayed on the Form (Associate Summary). I have modified my form with a command button and added this code.

```
Private Sub Command22_Click()
   DoCmd.OpenReport "Summary", acViewPreview, , "Name = " & Me.Combo8     
End Sub
```

This worked with the exception of asking me to type  in teh name for the report. Then it generated just as I want.  I tried adjusting to a field that wasnt a combo box assuming that the multiple values associated with the combo box were the problem.

```
Private Sub Command22_Click()
   DoCmd.OpenReport "Summary", acViewPreview, , "Name = " & Me.Text12     
End Sub
```

Text12 is an expression joining two fields with a comma.

```
=[Last] & ", " & [First]
result... Doe, John
```

When I use the command button now I recieve a debug with the following error.

```
Run-Time error '3075':
Syntax error (comma) in query expression '(Name = Doe, John)'.
```

Thoughts...

Comment: Ok Here is where I am now...    

    Private Sub rptPre_Click()
    On Error GoTo Err_rptPre_Click
    Dim stDocName As String
    stDocName = "Summary"
    DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, acPreview, _
    WhereCondition:="UserName='" & Me.txtUserName & "'"
    Exit_rptPre_Click:
    Exit Sub
    Err_rptPre_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_rptPre_Click    
End Sub

Still not taking the name into the report.

Comment: With this code I am back to the Enter Parameter Value msgbox.  I have verified that Option Explicit is set in the code.  Another interesting item is when I Debug the code I see my user name in the Me.txtUserName & "'" line of code, and to top it all off now the report brings up every record...  Ugh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `OpenReport` method's `WhereCondition` parameter to filter the report's record source.

So, assuming the form has a text box named `txtUserName` and the report's record source includes a field named `user_name`, use something like this in your command button's click event procedure:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "YourReportName", _
    WhereCondition:="user_name='" & Me.txtUserName & "'"
```

Actually you can make troubleshooting easier by using a string variable to hold *WhereCondition*.

```
Dim strWhere AS String
strWhere = "user_name='" & Me.txtUserName & "'"
Debug.Print strWhere ' <-- use Ctrl+g to open Immediate window and view this
DoCmd.OpenReport "YourReportName", WhereCondition:=strWhere
```

Comment: HansUP, that has helped but I am not there yet.  See my update to original question.

Comment: HansUp, I know this is the answer. However I have found some flaws in the design of my database.  I am going to go back and restructure and then I know this will work.  Thanks for your patience nad help!!!