# MS Access Report filtered, emailed via VBA

Tags: vba, email, ms-access

I have built a task-tracking database for my department. Tasks are assigned to staff in the "Assignee" field of the tasks table, which is actually a reference to the Staff table.

Once a week, I need to send out a report to each person, each report personalized to filter only those tasks they are assigned to.  Simple enough for me to create manually, but creating one for each person is time-consuming and tedious. I have found code for outputting and/or emailing a report, but neither allows me to filter the reports via VBA. Ideally, I would simply create a loop that would fire these reports off one by one, applying the filter and sending the email to the corresponding staffer (the Staff table also contains their emails). I'm open to an intermediate step where the report is first saved somewhere if this makes it easier.

I cannot find a way to filter a report via VBA as I am exporting or emailing it.  I have contemplated just creating the pre-filtered reports in advance and simply emailing these out, but this is not a dynamic method as it will not automatically account for staff changes, and I do not expect my successor to be VBA-friendly.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  SO questions are best when they ask a specific question rather than general programming help or guidance. See [How to Ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  If you're only asking about filtering via VBA then use `Report.Filter` and `Report.FilterOn` methods.  There are various ways to export and/or email, but you should research and attempt those as separate topics.  I'm certain those topics have been covered before on SO and probably on the web in tutorials and other forums.  Good luck.

Comment: A search right here on Stack Overflow for `[ms-access] open and filter report` returns at least a couple answers with good hints and even usable code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access form button to generate and filter existing report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863958/access-form-button-to-generate-and-filter-existing-report)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting a Multi-Page MS Access report into individual pdf files based on a Customer ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11498794/splitting-a-multi-page-ms-access-report-into-individual-pdf-files-based-on-a-cus)

Comment: I actually did do a lot of research before asking my question, and learned about Report.Filter and FilterOn, as well as the other methods listed in the things you cited (thank you for also doing research for me), but I was unclear on whether OutputTo would then take the currently opened form (I also wasn't relishing having to sit there and watch multiple reports open and close as it went through the procedure, but is that's what it takes...)