# use combobox to filter subreport and print results

Tags: ms-access

Basically, What I'm trying to do is print the sub report
based on the main forms combo box, I have my combo box set up
with master and child links and it filters the sub report. 
The issue is when trying to print the sub report it discards
the filter and what is shown and prints all the records. I'm not
sure how to keep the filter or pass the filter so that when I print
it only prints the visible records. The below pictures show what happens.

Main Form:
[image: Main Form]

Print Preview:
[image: Print Preview]

Comment: You need to pass the filter via the DoCmd.OpenReport when you click the 'Print' button.  See this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863958/access-form-button-to-generate-and-filter-existing-report

Comment: I tried what was stated there and it still does not work just causes a error in script

Comment: finally got the code to work but it asks for a parameter once you type it in it prints a blank page when its supposed to be opening the report

Comment: Please update your question and post: (1) the code you are using to open the report and (2) the query that the report uses as a record source.  I assume you are using a query, which may have the prompt, otherwise your code to open the report is not formatted correctly.